# How to create a button with QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I would like to create a button with QGIS but I haven't yet succeeded with this little exercise.

Is there a tutorial or someone who can help me?

Answer (score 3):

There are several examples and tutorials on the Net. See these tutorials for beginners:

- [Tutorial – Building A Simple Plugin](http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/plugins_tutorial.html)
- [A simple QGIS python plugin tutorial](http://linfiniti.com/2010/08/a-simple-qgis-python-tutorial/)

The main documentation to create plugins is the [pyqgis developer cookbook](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/index.html).